How to save a Wordpress page to my server with an iframe embedded in it
I have a Wordpress site that has a configuration product with a 3d iframe in it. When they use the page and design what they want via applying materials to that 3d image and selecting other variations I’m not able to see what they created. What would be ways to either save this back to the Wordpress site or download it to there pc. Then sent to us via email. Prefer the save method. I have tried html2canvas but get a blank pdf. It’s all from the same origin so not sure what is a good way to do it.
I have looked at html2canvas but no luck unless there is a way that I don’t know about.

I understand that I need to ask them to upload it. So are you saying to have the user take a screenshot using there clipping tool and then have an upload button so they can upload it? Or is there a way to have them click on a button and it saves it to my server? If I can save it to the server will it contain my iframe?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Using html2canvas to generate an image in PNG format can be useful to obtain a visual capture, but for more complex needs such as retrieving configuration data, directly interacting with the API of the configurator is more appropriate.
Without an API, directly retrieving data from the 3D configurator embedded in an iframe can be very limited.

Just need the image captured of what they used on my site. Don’t need anything else. I tried html2canvas but it was blank. I am using the same origin in that the website and I frame come from the same exact domain.
Does anyone have an example of using html2canvas with the same origin so I can see what I need to do.
